# Spring MVC Test In Fitnesse

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, fitnesse, spring-mvc-test

I have a probleme with Fitnesse Integration with Spring MVC .

My use case to test is the authentication :

I have a generic Fixture that load spring Context :

```
public abstract class GenericSpringFixture extends GenericBelFixture {

protected static AutowireCapableBeanFactory beanFactory;
protected static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context;

static {
    initSpring();
}

public static void initSpring() {
    if ((context == null) || !context.isActive()) {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/applicationContext-fitnesse-common.xml");
        beanFactory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
    }
}

public GenericSpringFixture() {
    beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);
}

public static AutowireCapableBeanFactory returnBeanFactory() {
    return beanFactory;
}
}
```

The applicationContext-fitnesse-common.xml file is loading all dependencies of My plateform and this include my servlet(Spring Mvc Files) config .

My fixture code is :

```
public class IdentificationUtilisateur extends GenericSpringFixture{

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

@Autowired
private FilterChainProxy springSecurityFilterChain;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

public void seLogerAvecIdentifiantEtMotDePasse(String identifiant,
        String motDePasse) {
    this.mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders
            .webAppContextSetup(this.webApplicationContext)
            .addFilters(this.springSecurityFilterChain).build();
}

public void accesReussi() throws Exception{
    mockMvc.perform(
            post("/j_spring_security_check")
                    .param("j_username", "bilal")
                    .param("j_password", "Pa1234567"));
}
}
```

The problem is that spring is not able to find any webApplicationContext .

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'ma.awb.ebk.bel.web.fixture.authentication.IdentificationUtilisateur':
>   Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire field: private
>   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext
>   ma.awb.ebk.bel.web.fixture.authentication.IdentificationUtilisateur.webApplicationContext;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   [org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext] found for
>   dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The only difference between My Slim fixture and my test Spring mvc is that in my test MVC , i am on a junit context and i have this annotation enabled on my Junit test :

```
@WebAppConfiguration
```

Thanks for your Help .

Answer (score 0):

You create an applicationContext in GenericSpringFixture, but it would not be able to autowire components in IdentificationUtilisateur.

@Autowire works if you annotate your test class with @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class) but I'm not sure if it works with you FitNess classes.

Maybe you need to inject them manually:

```
private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext = GenericSpringFixture.context()
```

Update1 (not noticed the autowired code snippet):
It seems ClassPathXmlApplicationContext is not a WebAppliactionContext. What about setting up an XmlWebApplicationContext instead?

Comment: This line in GenericSpringFixture is used to enable annotation ===>beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true); I have access to all my service,Repository , Component Via @Autowired excepting WebApplicationContext

Comment: GenericSpringFixture.context suggesion didn't work , i can't convert ClassPathXmlApplicationContext To WebApplicationContext

Comment: Sorry, my fault not noticed beanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(this, AutowireCapableBeanFactory.AUTOWIRE_BY_TYPE, true);